# Change css background position multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I want to preview the thumbnail of a video file on hover, like www.megavideo.com but i want to do it with a sprite file. 
Ex: my thumb is an image of 140px width and 560px height
when i go with my mouse hover a want to switch the background position 4 time (-140px) and loop that animation while the mouse is hover. 
Can someone help me with that ? I'm sorry for my bad english and I'm newb with jquery.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apply an event handler with [`$.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which uses [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to adjust one axis of the `background-position` property by -140px every second. Store the return value of `setTimeout` so you can later cancel it. When the value of that axis exceeded `-140 * 4`, where 4 is the number of frames of animation, then reset it to 0.

You can specify a second callback function with `.hover` which will fire when you stop hovering; use that function to cancel the callback you last set with `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but like I said I'm not familiar with javascript, can you be a bit more explicit please :) I found that http://jsfiddle.net/ayNPS/85/ but I not work with sprites ...

Comment: I have this but I dont know how to chage de backgroud position instead of the src

`code` var timer,
  count = 0,
  cycle = function(el){
    var s = el.attr('src'),
     root = s.substring( 0, s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
    count = (count+1)%4;
    el.attr('src', root + ((count==0) ? 'default' : count) + '.jpg');
 };

 $('.mb img').hover(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   cycle($this);
   timer = setInterval(function(){ cycle($this); }, 1000);
 }, function(){
   clearInterval(timer);
 });
 
}) `code`